# Is that correct to say 'with no music on'?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

As written in the title, is that correct to say:

'Can you dance with no music on?' or should I better say 'when the music is not playing'.

I am not sure if it's grammatically correct to say 'with no music on'. What I wanted to say is 'Can you e.g imagine the music is playing and dance?' (And don't care about the music).

Thanks for help.

Comment: I would say: To dance without music. Versus: without music on, which means without it playing from some type of music player.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your suggestions are grammatical and would be understood.

However, in this specific example you don't really need anything after **music**. The best construction would probably be

> Can you dance with **no music**?

Using ...*on* or ...*playing* unnecessarily specify or imply specifying the source of the music.

Answer (score -1):

Or You can say simply. Can you dance without music?

When you say something about to do/can do with negative things then you can use there without word before that things.

Comment: It would be best if you could add explanation to this answer.